# Debian 10 (Buster) slow desktop/GUI

Tags: driver, intel, nvidia, debian-buster

When installing Debian 10 (Buster) the desktop/GUI applications are slow. Opening applications (e.g. Firefox, Terminal,...) takes quite long and the system is not usable at all.

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

did not help at all. Apparently it is a problem with either the CPU or the GPU driver. I installed Debian on an Intel i5 + Nvidia GTX build (not sure if the GPU is responsible here as well).

The only info I could find was [this](http://www.tier1.jp/article/article-2019-why-gnome-gui-on-debian-slow-amd64-and-solution.html), but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the above link, it is a driver issue. Yet, the steps above did not fully solve it. As shown [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918087), 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' should be removed and 'firmware-misc-nonfree' should be installed. After rebooting, the problem was solved and the system is usable again

Comment: Had same problem, just installed Debian 10 Buster on Intel CPU i7 with NVIDIA GPU and GUI got useless, it is only in a usable (though still very slow) state when not opening any apps. To fix it: 1. Add non-free to repos from /etc/apt/sources.list  2. apt update and then apt install firmware-misc-nonfree 3. apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel 4. reboot

Comment: I tried that one before, but for me unfortunately it did not solve my problem. Maybe its worth a shot to test both ways!

Answer (score 5):

I have solved same problem by removing 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' and installing 'firmware-misc-nonfree':

**System Details:**

```
root@hostname:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

**Solution Steps Details:**

1. From terminal switch to *root* user.
2. Add *non-free* repository entry to */etc/apt/sources.list*:

   ```
   root@hostname:/# cat <<EOT >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   # Non-Free
   deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
   EOT
   ```
3. Update/Download packages information from all configured sources:

   ```
   root@hostname:/# apt update
   ```
4. install *firmware-misc-nonfree*:

   ```
   root@hostname:/# apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
   ```
5. Erase *xserver-xorg-video-intel*:

   ```
   root@hostname:/# apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
   ```
6. Reboot the system:

   ```
   root@hostname:/# systemctl reboot
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This was done on a fresh install of Debian 10!

After lots of problems with something similar to this and initially only booting to command line I thought I would add a guide to how I got this solved. - This is for newer systems where the nouveau driver does not work and probably most of the hardware like the network adapter does not work either.

If you have no GUI or a slow to non-responsive GUI type at the command line prompt:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

A list of links will populate the screen, edit and add the list entries to to look like the image found by clicking this link.
[image: Image of sources.list]

Run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Update the Kernel - you can check the backports repo for possible upgrades by installing aptitude (skip the next two if you don't want to check first)
NOTE a comprehensive guide to this found at the link and suggested [Comprehensive Guide - Upgrade Kernel](https://jensd.be/968/linux/install-a-newer-kernel-in-debian-10-buster-stable)

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

and running:

```
aptitude search linux-image
```

To upgrade to the latest version run:

```
sudo apt -t buster-backports upgrade
```

Restart your machine.

If your machine was not loading a GUI, it most probably will now, but you may experience slow or unresponsive GUI interaction.
You can check if you Kernel updated by running:

```
uname -r
```

Install Nvidia driver:

Open Konsole or your preferred terminal if GUI has loaded, else run from the command line of the loaded OS.

Run:

```
sudo apt install -t buster-backports nvidia-driver
```

There will be warnings if nouveau driver still installed - a reboot will sort this out.

You should be good to go, hopefully.

***** If you had an Nvidia driver already installed then it will need to be purged by running:

```
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-driver
```

then do the steps to install the new driver.

I am sure there are things I have left out, so if anyone wants they are free to edit, but hopefully this will help get someone on the right path and save them the hours it took me.

Comment: Copy/paste text (like `sources.list`) as text, into a code block.  Also, this answer seems to stop short; are you suggesting `sudo apt-get update` or `dist-upgrade` after that?  Or were the contents of `sources.list` *directly* causing slowness somehow?  e.g. by looking for an optical disk if that was uncommented?  Or do you mean do this and then do what's in one of the other answers?

Comment: I was checking the formatting - not posted here often so did not realise the formatting was shown below where one types - known for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if anyone is still having this problem, but I had it and fixed by updating my kernel and firmware from backports to Linux 5.7.